# What does A. R. in A. R. sodium nitrite mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, notation

I'm reading about a reaction from a 1970s organic chemistry book. It references A. R. sodium nitrite. What does the A. R. mean?

I see from online that "Ar" means aromatic ring. Is that the same thing?

But I've also seen "Sodium Nitrite, Granular, AR®" with a registered trademark, implying it might be a specific brand of Sodium Nitrite, but that didn't make sense. https://www.chemical.net/sodium-nitrite-acs

Are there different types of sodium nitrite?

Comment: Can it stand for Analytical Reagent, an equivalent to P.A. ( Per Analysis ), as the substance purity level ?

Comment: A.R. probably Analytic Reagent as a mark of purity. Maybe later on it became a trade mark.

Comment: This. AR = Analytical Reagent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I have completely answered, but here's my go:

**AR : (ANALYTICAL REAGENT)** : Reagents essential for analytical purpose and research work having high purity. If reagent meets the requirements of the *American Chemical Society Committee* on Analytical Reagents, it will be denoted as an *AR (ACS) reagent*.

Also see:

1. https://www.researchlab.in/?product-details/grade-of-purity/
2. [https://www.avantorsciences.com/pages/en/grade-definitions#:~:text=AR%E2%80%94The%20standard%20Macron%20Fine,an%20AR%20(ACS)%20reagent](https://www.avantorsciences.com/pages/en/grade-definitions#:%7E:text=AR%E2%80%94The%20standard%20Macron%20Fine,an%20AR%20(ACS)%20reagent).

**EDIT**:And note that it isn't a ***Analytical ring***

Comment: Thank you very much for setting me on the right foot. I was previously leaning towards the ring thing, but didn't think it really made sense.

Comment: @GFL Welcome..Anytime!